# videoview crashing when trying to change the video

Tags: android, video, crash, android-videoview, playback

video view is crashing when trying to chage the video url.
    please see the log.

```
at android.media.MediaPlayer._reset(Native Method)
at android.media.MediaPlayer.reset(MediaPlayer.java:1391)
at android.widget.VideoView.release(VideoView.java:624)
at android.widget.VideoView.openVideo(VideoView.java:308)
at android.widget.VideoView.setVideoURI(VideoView.java:243)
at android.widget.VideoView.setVideoURI(VideoView.java:233)
at com.xxx.xxx.JavaScriptInterface$5.run(JavaScriptInterface.java:151)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5034)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:807)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:623)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: there must be more in Your logcat...please show the full log. It´s desribed what exception is thrown and where this happens..

Comment: see this link for full log.       
This log from the /data/anr/traces_appname.txt                                           

http://pastebin.com/gpbQrm1S

Comment: Which looks like the crash in native